# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495 is not defined in JSONP AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX request to get some data from server. In order to limit the request (due to large amount of requests will break the server) I have set timeout for the request. I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495 is not defined

Can anyone please help me to fix

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,  // some url link here
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status) {
        // some stuffs
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // some stuffs
    }
});
```

I have referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865065/ajax-call-using-jsonp-returns-error-uncaught-referenceerror-jquery1910275411515).
and tried adding property like `{'jsonpcallback':'mycallback'}`. But it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the request completing after the 5-second timeout? If so, this behavior is 100% by design: the error is telling you that the request will not be completed because it took longer than your specified `timeout` limit.

Comment: can you tell me how to handle the requests which exceeds the specified time limit. So that this issue may fix @apsillers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the request is taking longer than your specified `timeout` limit. When a request takes longer than the `timeout` limit, the request is considered a failure and should never complete. If you want to tolerate requests that take longer than five seconds to complete, you should specify a higher `timeout` value (or leave it out entirely, if you can accept waiting indefinitely).

JSONP works by loading a file in a `<script>` element of the form

```
jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495({ some: "data" });
```

This causes a function called `jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495` to run, with some data as an argument. jQuery automatically sets up a function called `jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495` when it requests that script file from the server (which is a function that ultimately calls your `success` function). However, when you set a `timeout`, jQuery *removes* that function when the timeout time window ends, so you see the error `jQuery22303175114964962158_1470743444495 is not defined` because the `<script>` loads, but the function it calls no longer exists after five seconds.

Suppose I wanted my friend to come by my house to give me a screwdriver. We have the following exchange over the phone:

> ME: Hi, friend! Please let me borrow your screwdriver. Can you drop it off at my house?
>
> FRIEND: I'd love to. Where can I leave it?
>
> ME: I am putting a purple basket on my porch. Please leave it in there.

Since you are setting a timeout, in this analogy you also decide to remove the purple basket after waiting five hours.  When your friend shows up six hours later, he doesn't see the purple basket (because you took it back inside an hour before) and says

> FRIEND: Error: purple basket not found!

The solution here is, of course, not to remove the purple basket (i.e., don't set a `timeout` value) unless you really have a good reason to reject responses after a fixed period of time. If you *do* have a good reason to reject responses after a fixed period of time, then it's not a problem if your requests fail after that period of time: it's *exactly* what you asked for.

Since you *don't* want your requests to always fail after five seconds, don't set a `timeout: 5000` which causes your requests to fail after five seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. It helps me to find out my mistake.. Is there any other way *(without removing the timeout value)* to fix this problem?

Comment: @Jeni I fully don't understand what your problem *is*. The purpose of a `timeout` value is to cause the request to fail after a certain amount of time, and that's exactly what's happening, right? If you don't want the functionality`timeout` supplies, don't use it. If you do want that functionality, do use it. What exactly do you want `timeout` to do that is isn't doing (or what is it doing that you wish it weren't doing)?

Comment: Yes I agreed your point.. After removing `timeout` its works fine for me.. I was thinking to abort those response which are came after 5 seconds. But now I got some idea... Thanks a lot :-)  @apsillers

Answer (score 0):

Despite it is in fact desired action because anonymous function is being removed after timeout and does not exists any more as answered before, it is still possible to catch that exception via global exception handler.

```js
window.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('Exception: "' + e + '"');
    return true;
};
```

This one will still generate console log 'Exception: "Script error."' but it won't be an uncaught exception anymore.